# Javascript bookmarklet to select drop down value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bookmarklet

Was hoping you guys can help me out. I can't seem to figure out how to make a bookmarklet to selecting options on a drop-down menu on a webpage.

**Hoping to achieve:** make a bookmark on my chrome browser. When I click it on this page it will select the drop-down and select level 2 in the membership box

html of the webpage

```html
<select name="membership" onchange="submit()">
<option value="1"> Level 1</option>
<option value="2"> Level 2</option>
<option value="3"> Level 3</option>
```

thanks. Really new to this.

**Edit:** Sorry I apologize. This is the current bookmark I tried to make

javascript:document.getElementById("membership").selectedIndex = 2; <

**EDIT2** < realized probably can't use get element by id since the `<select name="membership"` is using name instead of `id`. Is there one that can search the name=?

**EDIT 3** THANKS EVERYONE for your help here you guys are amazing and I've learned a lot in the past 2 hrs with the different types of getElements* and queryselector. thanks sideroxylon!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So did you come here expecting others to write all the code for you? that's not how this site works. The idea is for you to show what you tried that isn't working and we help fix ***your code***

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask.HINT: Post effort and code

Comment: I'd start with `document.querySelector("[name=membership]").selectedIndex=1` Possible followed by `;submit()`

Comment: currently i have  document.getElementById("membership").selectedIndex = 2; but when i put it in my bookmark nothing happens when i click on it. 

i thought that would work sorry didnt post waht i tried in my original post i updated it now.
@charluefl

Comment: Do you want the second option selected (i.e. trigger the onchange function), or just displayed?  If the latter, just add `selected`inside the `option` tag.

Comment: @sideroxylon i want to trigger the onchange function. But atm im having a hard time to selecting level 2 in the dropbox.  Even when i change it to look for value instead. it opens the page as blank with the words Level 2 `javascript:document.querySelector("[name=membership]").value = 'Level 2';` . im going to try using getElementById

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might get you started.  First up you select the option you want.  Then trigger the `onchange` event. Make sure you're passing the selected value.

```js
document.getElementsByName('membership')[0].value = 2;
document.getElementsByName('membership')[0].onchange();

function submit(val) {
  alert(val);
}
```

```html
<select name="membership" onchange="submit(this.value)">
  <option value="1">Level 1</option>
  <option value="2">Level 2</option>
  <option value="3">Level 3</option>
</select>
```

Your bookmarklet should look something like this:

`javascript:document.getElementsByName('membership')[0].value = 2;document.getElementsByName('membership')[0].onchange();`

Comment: YES this works! wow. i was getting close to it haha. Thank you! @sideroxylon and everyone here i've learned alot in the past 2 hours

Comment: sorry one last beginner question what does [0] do exactly.

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns a collection of nodes - even if there is only one.  You need to access the collection by index (zero indexed) - so `[0]` is the first in the collection..

Comment: thanks again! will keep that in mind for the future!